# Filter executed before j_security_check

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have a filter mapped to /* and my security constraint is mapped to /*.

The filter perfoms a request forward when the application is not configured (an entry in the database).

When I access the application I am expecting to see the login page that is served up by the j_securit_check but instead the filter is executed and the forward is performed. This ends in a loop as I never get to the login page.

I thought security checks were performed *before* filters were processed?

This is WebSphere 8.0.0.4. It functions fine under Tomcat and JBoss.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another response from IBM. They suggest forwarding from a filter will never be secured by j_security_check so be careful when using WebSphere. Jboss and Tomcat do not behave like this.

### I had the Webcontainer developer to take a look at this too and received the following update:

The web.xml shows the [configFilter] is mapped to /*
i.e.
configFilter
        /*

and also security is mapped to all
i.e.
General Auth.
            /*

The inbound request is for [/rootFilter/test/test-page.jsp], security is
called and then it is redirected to [rootFilter/login.jsp].
Now for the request [rootFilter/login.jsp], since the filter
[configFilter]] is mapped to all request ,
[configFilter] is executed which forwards the request to
[/rootFilter/test/test-page.jsp] and then test-page.jsp is served.

According to Java Servlet Specification in 13.2 Declarative Security ,
the security is not valid for any dispatched request so the forwarded
request to [/rootFilter/test/test-page.jsp] the security is not checked.

Here is from specification,
The security model applies to the static content part of the web
application and to
servlets and filters within the application that are requested by the
client. The
security model does not apply when a servlet uses the RequestDispatcher
to invoke
a static resource or servlet using a forward or an include.

Customer will need to look into the design of the application to make
sure either the filter is not mapped to all the requests or the filter
does not forward to another resource.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you should not be able to intercept j_security_check calls because of sevcurity reasons.

Sounds like a bug in Webspehere (I googled it, and it was a bug/feature in older versions of Websphere, not sure about 8.0.0.4)

Comment: yes that is my understanding. I am not trying to intercept and do not want to :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, however you can map a filter on j_security_check for post authentication processing or you can code your own custom login module or Trust Association Interceptor 
see example here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1112_deluca/1112_deluca.html

Comment: I think you miss the point, I can't do what? I should be able to put a filter mapped to /* that should be behind/protected by/secured by j_security_check this is what I want and I can do this in older WAS and tomcat and JBOss. I think you misunderstood the question I am not trying to intercept j_security_check or post/pre process around j_security_check. I do not want that to happen but that *is* what is happening making my app insecure

Comment: You are right I did not understand your question, I thought you wanted to intercept calls to j_security_check before WAS does. Have you enabled global security on WAS?

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected if I map the security constraint to /* and then the filters to just / (no wild card).

This is the reponse I got from IBM regarding why it runs servlet filters *before* running a security check.

> Security L3 spoke to a developer in the Webcontainer team. He said
>   that it is WAD for servlet filters to run first. j_security_check is a
>   web resource, and like with all web resource requests servlet filters
>   will run first. So that is the short answer to the your concern.
>   Security L3 looked at the flow of requests. It seems that the way the
>   filter is coded, the login.jsp result is never returned to the client,
>   hence there is never a j_security_check ever done. Can see that the
>   filter does a
>   "request.getRequestDispatcher("test/test-page.jsp").forward(request,
>   response);". The developer said that forward() requests are not auth
>   checked, again WAD. So keep the following in minf when re-design the
>   servlet filters.
>
> - 1 Servlet filters will be called before j_security_check or any web resouse.
> - 2 using request.getRequestDispatcher().forward() disables auth checks.

I will not be redesigning my filters as it works as expected when running under Tomcat or JBoss. The only thing that needs to be changed is the mapping in the web.xml.